# Colors = Crayons?

Tags: american-english, dialects, colors

I always considered the word "colors" as synonymous with the word "crayons," e.g. "the teacher asked her students to take out their colors" would mean "the teacher asked her students to take out their crayons."

By extension, I always thought "coloring" meant "using crayons" (moreover, to the exclusion of colored pencils, markers, etc.).

However, these usages came up at work today, and everyone thought I was odd for these assumptions.

Am I totally off-base, or are these regionalisms of which I've been unaware?

(If it helps, I was born, raised and continue to live in central Wisconsin, and the same goes for my parents.)

Comment: "Colors" may refer to crayons, markers, pencils, paints, chalks, or what have you. A teacher can tell students to take out their books without specifying which ones. Given the context, the students will just know what is meant by such general terms.

Comment: The words 'colors' and 'crayons' _are_ synonymous (ie they're interchangeable in some situations). But the overlap of their senses is quite small. Similarly, my first thought when reading 'crayons' was of the wax variety, but 'coloured pencils' is synonymous here. And certainly restricting 'colouring' to 'using a pencil' or 'using a wax crayon' is not stadard usage. Think of adding say dye (**color** v.t.
18. to give or apply color to; tinge; paint; dye.) {[R H K Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/colour)}.

Comment: When I was growing up, in suburban Louisville KY, "crayon" meant "Crayola" or some cheap imitation, but "colors" (almost always plural) would sometimes be used to mean "crayons" (as in "Now everyone take out your colors and color in the picture in your lesson").  "Colors" was less common than "crayons", but was universally understood.  I've heard the term used similarly in other parts of the country, so I don't think it's limited to small parts of the US.

Comment: (Note that a book containing outlines of pictures that are intended to have coloration applied using crayons is known as a "coloring book".  Yes, some are suitable for use with colored pencils, and, these days, a child might be more apt to use colored felt markers, but it's been a "coloring book" since 1955, at least, well before felt markers (other than permanent black) were available, and well before even colored pencils were commonly used in classrooms.)

Comment: @HotLicks: a coloring book is called that because the intent is to add color (as in red, blue, yellow, green, etc.) to the pictures. There is absolutely no implication about what medium those colors will be in (wax, chalk, alcohol, water, acrylic, oil, whatever).

Comment: For what it's worth, I've never encountered this usage of "colors". To my mind, it's totally wrong: wax crayons may be ubiquitous in schools, but to equate such an inferior coloring implement with "coloring", as if no other possibility existed, is ... I have no words, it's so *wrong*.

Comment: In AusEng the noun colours only refers to the colours themselves, not any artistic medium.

Comment: Absent other context, *colors* to my mind are clothes with school colors— *get out your colors* would mean the children should retrieve their school sweatshirts or blazers or jerseys or scarves or whatnot for a pep rally or some such. Similarly, in my college fraternity days, *letters* were clothes bearing the fraternity's letters; *remember to wear letters to the hockey game*.

Answer (score 7):

As a parent, if I were to tell my child *to color* (v), she could take out her markers or crayons or colored pencils. The northeastern US parent and child would not use *colors* as a noun; instead, he or she would say specifically, "Take out your crayons/markers/colored pencils."

Comment: This is similar to my experiences in the southern US (Texas/Louisiana)

Comment: Or "pencil crayons" in Canada.

Comment: This is true for California as well.

Comment: The number of NE US parents and children is large. In my (limited) experience, your claim about what they would not do is untrue.

Comment: Just to update--I said to my daughter yesterday, "Why don't you color (v.)?" to which she replied, "I can't find my colors." !!! So there you go.

Answer (score 6):

The use of 'crayon' became muddled in the 20th century by the advent and use of Crayola crayons in 1903. Designed for use by children--safe, non-toxic--generations of children now grown understand 'crayon' to designate specifically waxy coloring sticks, that is, 'Crayola' brand crayons. In fact, however, 'crayon' (noun) was and still is used to mean

> a. A *pointed stick or pencil* of coloured chalk or *other material*, for drawing.

(from the [OED](http://www.oed.com/), italics mine)

The use as a noun, from Latin *creta* (chalk) via French, is first recorded in English around 1660. Likewise, the verbal use ('to draw with a crayon').

So, your idea that the use of 'crayon' meaning specifically a *waxy non-toxic* coloring stick [usually or always branded "Crayola"], [started out as] a regionalism, has some basis in fact: that use arose and spread with the Crayola brand of crayon. 'Crayola' itself was invented by the wife of one of the inventors of the waxy, non-toxic crayons, who compounded the French word for chalk and part of the French word for 'oily'.

For a history of Crayola crayons see, for example, ["Crayola Crayon History"](http://inventors.about.com/od/cstartinventions/a/crayons.htm).

### Edit: Response to Comment on this Answer by OP

Your parenthetical statement in the question ("to the exclusion of colored pencils, markers, etc.") sponsored my conclusion that the usage muddle arising from the dominance of Crayola brand waxy, non-toxic crayons in the crayon market was at least partly to blame for the usage issue you encountered at work.

Your comment on this answer clarified your central concern with the usage of 'colors' and 'coloring', while at the same time acknowledging that part of the issue at work might have come from your understanding of 'crayon' as meaning specifically waxy crayons. When you clarified your concerns in your response to my answer, you defined your questions more precisely. You asked whether

1. "'crayons' can be called 'colors'",

and whether

2. "'coloring' is understood to be done most often with crayons (if not exclusively)".

As I point out in my response to your comment (and elaborate here), the answer to your first question ("can crayons be called colors") is **yes**. The [OED](http://www.oed.com/), for example, gives the following definition under the headword **colour | color, n.**:

> III. A coloured object, and related senses.
>
> 18. a. A substance used to give something a particular colour ....

This is the sense you encountered in school. Even if the noun sense of 'color' was not as a matter of definition applied to a substance used to impart color to something, figuratively used (in *synecdoche* or *metonymy*), 'color' denotes the substance used to impart color.

Now, as I indicate in my response to your comment (and elaborate here), the answer to your second question is, with qualifications, **no**. Simply, 'coloring' is understood to be done with *whatever* substance is or might be used, whether it be wax, chalk, graphite, paint, ink or any other; in fact, no substance at all need be understood, because 'color' is a quality of light. A rainbow, for example, colors the sky.

However, I suspect your question pertains to a local, that is, a local educational, context, as given in your example ("the teacher asked her students ...."). *In that case,* the answer to your second question might well be **yes**. In a local educational context, 'coloring' may well be understood by students to mean coloring with whatever substance and instrument is most frequently or *always* at hand, including crayons. This situationally specific interpretation of 'coloring' is a *localism* (rather than a *regionalism*), and a *narrow localism*.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. My question was whether "crayons" can be called "colors," and whether "coloring" is understood to be done most often with crayons (if not exclusively). I get what you're saying, though, that my issue might be simply a too-narrow concept of what a "crayon" (i.e. a "color") is in the first place.

Comment: I don't think "**crayon** = *waxy non-toxic coloring stick*" is a regionalism, or if it is, it's a very widespread one (covering all of the US at least). What the question is asking about is "**color** = *waxy non-toxic coloring stick*", which emphatically IS a regionalism, and one that's Totally Wrong to people who aren't covered by the affected region.

Comment: @Khromy, that's 2 questions. (1) Yes: sense III 18 a in the OED is "A substance used to give something a particular colour", and that *is* a common use; (2) No, not in general, but *depending on the local context*, that understanding might be common. For example, in a school environment (as per your example), where crayons (of whatever type) are the usual coloring implement, your example could easily be common--that is, "colors" in that local environment might frequently or always mean "crayons". As an aside, I think you're *partly* on the right track with the "too-narrow concept" issue.

Comment: The word *crayon* is simply the French, for a writing/drawing stick. But at school in Britain in the 50s we were encouraged to call the pencil variety *coloured pencils*,  the word *crayon* reserved for the wax type. The *Pencil Museum* is at Keswick, in Cumbria, which was the home to the famous [*Lakeland Pencil Company*](https://www.mintprice.com/p/lakeland-coloured-pencil-33329?rmd=ggle001&gclid=Cj0KEQjwvJqvBRCL77m2-uKczsIBEiQAkx8VjMogq7FRcVAetm8OaixQmHmgaA8_jH_bqLNyMQbs2pYaAmbA8P8HAQ). If you look on their advertisement you do not see the word *crayon* anywhere!

Comment: @WS2, I'd been hoping a Brit would chime in with some clues about how and when the US muddle was exported. Thanks. It seems that by the 50s the wax-identity had been mostly applied to *crayon* in Britain? That (loose) constriction of the sense of *crayon* was certainly in place in the US by the 50s.

Comment: @JEL [The Derwent Pencil Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derwent_Cumberland_Pencil_Company) is the actual name of the manufacturer of Lakeland pencils (now owned by ACCO Brands). This Wiki article tells you all about them from their starting in 1832. Are you saying that colouring pencils used to be called *crayons*? My sense is that Derwent always called theirs *pencils*.

Comment: @JEL But Crayola colours did not arrive on the scene until 1903. The Derwent Cumberland Pencil Company had been around since 1832.

Comment: @WS2, Yes. *Crayon* in both contemporary and historical use is a synonym of *pencil*. OED= 1. a. A pointed stick or pencil of coloured chalk or other material, for drawing. More interesting, historically, *pencil* meant what we now call *paintbrush*.

Comment: @JEL So are you telling me that wooden pencils (coloured and otherwise) used to be called *crayons*, before *Crayola* raised its ugly head?

Comment: @WS2, yes, pencils were and are *also* called crayons. The contemporary sense of *pencil* varies from the historical sense (*paintbrush*). The transitional period (I speculate) for these various uses (pencil-painbrush-crayon) corresponded with the frenchification of English via upper class British pretensions.

Comment: @JEL I have been around a fair while, and I can never in my life remember anyone, when speaking English, referring to an ordinary *pencil* as a *crayon*. Can you supply any examples from literature?

Comment: @WS2, What is an "ordinary" pencil? You mean not a drawing pencil? I'm not sure how to distinguish an ordinary pencil from a drawing pencil, in literature or otherwise.

Comment: @JEL There is no evidence from the OED that *crayon* was ever applied to the graphite pencil - only to colouring chalks etc.

Comment: @WS2, I'm not sure what to display as proof...I've already cited the pertinent OED definition of *crayon* ("A ... pencil of ... other material [used] for drawing"). Let's see, how about [lumber crayons](http://lumber-crayon.com/carpenter-pencil.html)?

Comment: @JEL Yes, the OED says *A pointed stick, or pencil of coloured chalk or other material for drawing*. That does not suggest a graphite pencil, nor do the examples given. This is a potted  [history of the graphite pencil](http://pencils.com/pencil-history/). Nowhere does it mention the word *crayon*.

Comment: @WS2, Perhaps anecdotal evidence? I think we're talking at cross-purposes now. When I reached my majority (4 decades ago), I cohabited with a visual artist. She confounded me by refering to her pencils (yes, including wood-encased graphite for blacks) as *crayons*. "Those aren't crayons, they're pencils!" I told her. She shook her head. After several rounds of this, she showed me the box, clearly marked in English, "crayons". So, I don't think whether the substance of color (ahem) is graphite, wax, chalk or another, has any real bearing on the issue. Perhaps *use* of the instrument?

Comment: @JEL A professional's terminology is going to differ from that of the general public, and matters not as to how well-understood or well-received the specialist's use will be among the uninitiated. FedEx carries no passengers but is an *airline*; diocesan Catholic priests are *secular*; the all-female Kappa Kappa Gamma is not a sorority but a *fraternity*. Describe them as such and expect quizzical looks. In my childhood *crayons* meant wax crayons, and never gum crayons (*pastels*) or pencil crayons (*colored pencils*), or chalk crayons (*chalk*), and I venture that most Americans would agree.

Comment: @choster, a very good point, although I can offer several rebuttals worth considering. I'm not sure I will--this topic has been beaten to death--and, you being a professional dilettante, I'm fairly sure you understand why not. As points of curiosity, how old are you? Have you ever had an interest in the visual arts, professional or amateur? (I ask this last because box labels describing contents including graphite pencils as crayons are not exceptional.) Anyway (and more to the point), I think my edited answer addresses the OP's question very well.

Answer (score 0):

You are not strange...I heard this in school.  I went to school in the Midwest, West coast, and also the south (Louisiana.). We had crayons and markers.

Comment: Likewise (hence the upvote). My early schooling was in S. Illinois, Oklahoma, and Minnesota.